# What does "di" stand for in linux kernel image file

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to find the kernel packages i need.

What does `di` stand for in `kernel-image-3.13.0-47-generic-di_3.13.0-47.78~precise1_i386`?

Comment: Where is that kernel package located at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "di" in the file name or the debian.master/d-i directory in the source structure means "Debian Installer".

Here is an excerpt from the [Debian glossary](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary):

"Debian Installer (D-I)

```
Debian Installer is the software used to initially install Debian on your hard disk. This should not be confused with the software used to install additional packages on a running Debian system (see APT). "
```

Answer (score 3):

`di` means "debian installer".

[See the packages site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty-updates/debian-installer/).